# Crossrider external js file not loading :PDFJS is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension, crossrider

Below are my codes in extension.js. If you look at the codes, I tried different ways to load the file to my extension. No matter what, I always getting

**VM3051:15 Uncaught ReferenceError: PDFJS is not defined**

Tried with putting the file in different locations.

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  console.log("pdf min js loading");
  appAPI.resources.includeJS('jspdf.js');
 // appAPI.resources.includeJS('js/jspdf.js');
// appAPI.resources.includeRemoteJS('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.min.js');
 //$.globalEval(appAPI.resources.get('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.min.js'));
 console.log("done");
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert(window.location.href);
    if(window.location.href.indexOf(".pdf") > -1) {
        console.log("its a pdf");

        alert("pdf");
        var doc = new jsPDF();

    }else{
    alert($.trim($('div').find('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,p,span').text()));
    }

    },6000);
});
```

Here is the file structure

[image]

I cannot modify `manifest.json` because the extension should be unique for all the browsers not just for chrome.

Comment: Note: `window.location.href.indexOf(".pdf") > -1` isn't reliable. Use something like `window.location.href.endsWith(".pdf")`.

Comment: @gcampbell Yes .. sure. I'll update it soon. Just testing now.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ, I guess you mean `jspdf.min.js`, could you please also provide `manifest.json`?

Comment: @HaibaraAi Yes. Just added my manifest. And also tried putting it in lib folder of extension and given the path in manifest. Still the same error.

Comment: File structure screenshot is hardly useful as it's incomplete and contains extra paths like `Resources` that aren't used in the posted code. There's also a capital letter in `Settings.json` so make sure the file name is exactly the same or simply *always* use lowercase.

Comment: @wOxxOm Settings json is fine and if you readed full code, `// appAPI.resources.includeJS('js/pdf.js');` is access the files from js folder of resources.

Comment: Crossrider [documentation](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.resources) says each resource is limited to 100kB, but pdf.js is larger. Maybe that's why it's not loaded. Actually, I'm not sure why you don't load it as a normal content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm The pdf js is already minified and I cannot (don't know) how to reduce its size further. Yaa I tried the content script way, no luck. Added the path in manifest as content script (tried full path (http://...  & js/jspdf.min.js)) with no luck. Do you see any problem in  using the codes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm confused, the two CloudFlare URLs in your code reference the project [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF). I would assume the local `pdf.js` does the same too.

In your code, you're using

```
PDFJS.getDocument();
```

This syntax comes from [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) which is a totally different project from Mozilla.

If you're sticking with [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF), your code should be something like:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world.');
doc.save('Test.pdf');
```

Or you'll need to include the correct library for [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/).

After the edits you've made and your comments, it seems you've switch completely over to [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) but you're still getting the same error which clearly mentions [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/).

Are you sure you're debugging the correct and last version of your app which is only using [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)?

I've setup a small reproduction example on [Crossrider](http://crossrider.com/) using only [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF).

[image: Project structure]

The *extension.js* code is the following:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  console.log("pdf min js loading");

  appAPI.resources.includeJS('jspdf.js');

  console.log("done");

  var doc = new jsPDF();

  console.log(doc);
});
```

When debugging the extension, I'm getting this result:

[image: Output]

`doc` is an object containing an instance of [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) which I can later use.

There should be no mention of [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) whatsoever. My only guess could be that you're running / debugging a version of your extension still containing references to this project.

Comment: Edited a bit. Hope that clears. I am just using jsPdf and tried using different ways of loading it. When I use in content scripts it is working. But it questions the support of mozilla and intenet explorer.

Comment: So what's the error now, I'm assuming you're not getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: PDFJS is not defined` anymore since you switched to jsPDF ?

Comment: I am getting the same error. The problem is it is not being loaded through jquery getScript or eval or inline etc. It is working only through content scripts

Comment: I've edited my answer to add a working example with no error mentioning PDF.js and a wild guess on why you would get reference to this project without using it.

Comment: Thanks Man. You made it possible. I tried many other ways and failed. If I remember correctly, I tried this way too :) But a fresh start might cleared off the things. Thanks again.